# Form.Invoke freezes the UI

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, freeze

I have been googling around for about an hour, and I still don't found any solution.

I simply try to set the maximum value of a progressbar from another thread. So I found the Control.Invoke method. I've been going ahead and implement it:

[image]

Now, when I debug my App it simply stucks at the `this.Invoke` line. The UI comes up, and it is frozen. So I was going ahead and google that out, and it told me to use `this.BeginInvoke()`. I implemented it, and I was fine, the UI don't freeze.
Thats quiet nice, but in fact the maximum value of my progress bar didn't change :(

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Maybe that helps: I am using `Parallel.Invoke();` to manage my thread ...

Comment: I am curious what was so secret it was pixelated out :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Control.Invoke` will only block when it is called on a worker thread and the UI thread is blocked.

The code you posted is correct. You must be blocking the UI thread somewhere else.

Comment: You where right! Since I was using `Parallel.Invoke` in my UI/main-Thread it was busy waiting for `Parallel.Invoke` to finish running. So it was nit able to update the property of my progressbar.

Answer (score 2):

I use something similar below in my application which I use to update the actual value for the progress bar. I have changed it a bit from your example. Give it a whirl and see if it helps :)

```
    public void SetMax(int value)
    {
        if (this.ProgressBar_status.InvokeRequired)
        {
           this.BeginInvoke(new Action<int>(SetMax), value);
           return;
        }
        this.ProgressBar_status.Maximum = value;
    }
```

Comment: The maximum value just stays, already found that solution at the web ;)

Comment: When you are debugging, if you put a breakpoint on the line which should set the maximum value does it get hit?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest it is better to use Background worker component which supports reporting progress in the progress bar including other features rather than to call invoke and BeginInvoke. You can find more details about background worker at below MSDN link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8dcext2.aspx

Comment: I know about the background worker class, know how to use etc. but I need a solution for my problem no alternative solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and thanks to Nicholas' answer I realised I had fallen into the same trap in a GUI app to debug a class used in a windows service. The service class runs most of it's code in a thread. The thread was calling back to a logging procedure when it stopped. I was stopping it using a button, and the logging used invoke to update a textbox. The problem was so simple I kicked myself - the invoke was waiting for the button-click to finish, which was waiting for the class to stop which was waiting for invoke to log that it was stopping (repeat until task-manager end process). Solved by creating a thread in the stop button click, with a threadproc to stop the service class. This meant I had to put more code to update form *after* the stop in another invoke from the new thread, but that worked ok as it wasn't waiting for the main form thread.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, mistake was using **join()** after starting thread.
join() prevents main thread from execution of codes before child thread completion.
I removed join() command and moved codes after join() to thread and everything worked fine.