# Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...) not dispatching anything

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher, begininvoke

I'm trying to get a lot of images from a webserver, so not to overload the server with hundreds of requests per second I only let a few through which is handled in WebService. The following code is on the object that saves the image, and where all the binding goes to.

```
ThreadStart thread = delegate()
{
    BitmapImage image = WebService.LoadImage(data);

    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        this.Image = image;
    }));
};

new Thread(thread).Start();
```

The image is loaded just fine, the UI works fluidly while the image loads, however `this.Image = image` is never called. If I use `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(..)` the line is called, but doesn't work for setting the Image.
Why doesn't the dispatcher invoke my action?

Comment: what happens if you use `Dispatcher.Invoke` instead of `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`? Maybe you ran into [the same problem that I ran into](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092098/form-invoke-freezes-the-ui).

Comment: have a look on how to use Invoke on this.Image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367718/c-automating-the-invokerequired-code-pattern

Comment: @GameScripting If I use `Dispatcher.Invoke` I get the error `Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you create you `BitmapImage` on a worker thread, it's not owned by the WPF thread.
Maybe this code can help you to solve the issue:

**The code you posted**

```
ThreadStart thread = delegate()
{
    BitmapImage image = WebService.LoadImage(data, Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);

    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        this.Image = image;
    }));
};

new Thread(thread).Start();
```

**How you could change your `WebService.LoadImage` to "make it work"**

```
BitmapImage LoadImage(object data, Dispatcher dispatcher)
{
    // get the raw data from a webservice etc.
    byte[] imageData = GetFromWebserviceSomehow(data);

    BitmapImage image;

    // create the BitmapImage on the WPF thread (important!)
    dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=>
    {
        // this overload does not exist, I just want to show that
        // you have to create the BitmapImage on the corresponding thread
        image = new BitmapImage(imageData);
    }));

    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Object
    |-> System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject
        |-> System.Windows.DependencyObject
            |-> System.Windows.Freezable
                |-> ... 
                    |-> System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage
```

`BitmapImage` is thread affined. So `this` control and `BitmapImage` object should be created in the same thread.
Also you can try to just Freeze image, but it seems it will not help.

`BeginInvoke` does not reveal error because it is handled by WPF. See MSDN how to set up WPF tracing.

WPF is single threaded. Read some book about WPF where all staff described.